Mobile Responsive Website breaking in Landscape mode

I'm attaching the picture of the problem I'm facing, when I load the website in landscape mode, one of the divs become large and exceed the page length and creates white space on the side of the screen
I think this is the div that's causing it:


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div id=MyCarousel class="carousel slide" data-ride=carousel style="height:90vh">
        <!--global parent div
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
                </li>
                <li data-target="#MyCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
                    <!--please refer note on div
                                    </li>
                                    </ol>-->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="container">
              <h1>
                <src="https://i.ibb.co/yBhYM5d/white-paper.png" alt="Infographic" width="150" height="150">
              </h1>
              <p> Trusted by a million users</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 custom-btn">
                <!--"btn btn-lg btn-primary"-->
                Request a Demo!
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <!--if you add a new PLEASE create a new Li item-->
            <div class="container">
              <h1><img src="https://i.ibb.co/px0bpy7/white-blood-cell.png" alt="Infographic" width="150" height="150"></h1>
              <p> 20 DeFi instruments</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 custom-btnB">
                <!--"btn btn-lg btn-primary"-->
                Pay for Subscription
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--carousel inner div-->




I've replicated your code in a JSFiddle (with an assumption that you're using Bootstrap, which had not been included in your code snippet) and it does not look like your screenshot. It seems you may have omitted some CSS to reproduce the issue. Consider providing this so we can help troubleshoot the undesired behavior you are experiencing please.

Hi Wongjn, thanks a lot and slr i fixed it somehow by manipulating the container fluid and such and encasing everything in one.
not sure if i can close this
